# Verification of integral bounds for $\mathbf F(x,y,z)=\langle \sin(yz),x^2y+\cos(z),y^2z+e^{xy} \rangle$

Tags: calculus

Let $\mathbf F$ denote the vector field: $\mathbf F(x,y,z)=\langle \sin(yz),x^2y+\cos(z),y^2z+e^{xy} \rangle$

Find the flux of $\mathbf F$ across the surface $S$ that encloses the solid bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and the planes $z=y-2$ and $z=0$, and is oriented outwards.

I set up the integral as such:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{rsin-2} = r^3 dzdrd\theta$$

$$= -16\pi$$

My classmate is adamant that this is wrong and the integral should be:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{rsin-2}^{0} = r^3 dzdrd\theta$$

$$= 16\pi$$

If someone could please confirm which one is indeed correct that would be great!

Comment: $z=y-2$ is below $z=0$ inside the cylinder, your classmate is right.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to confirm this!